# How to check if a folder is actually an alias in C (macOS)?

Tags: c, macos, directory, filesystems

I'm writing a simple recursive program that looks for specific files in a certain directory tree on macOS.
Problem is, if it finds an alias to a folder that is above the current directory on the same branch of the tree it starts to loop infinitely and crashes after a while with segmentation fault (after only 252 levels or so of recursion it seems, which appears to be a low number to me by the way). I tried to modify my code not to navigate files which are symbolic links, but it still navigates those aliases.

Here's an example structure of directories(every line has at the left the name of some folder, at the right its contents):

folder1: folder2

folder2: folder1(alias)

These are some lines taken out from the code I wrote, updated to be complete(without frees and error checks):

```
char *name = //target file name
int myfind(){
    DIR *curr_dir = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *next_entry;
    struct stat info;
    char *entry_name;
    char *path;
    while((next_entry = readdir(curr_dir)) != NULL){
        entry_name = next_entry->d_name;
        //ignore . and ..
        if(strcmp(entry_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(entry_name,"..") == 0)
            continue;
        stat(entry_name, &info);
        if(strncmp(name, entry_name, 255) == 0){
            path = realpath(entry_name, NULL);
            //print info about file found
        }
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode) && !S_ISLNK(info.st_mode)){ 
            char *prev_path = getwd(NULL);
            chdir(entry_name);
            myfind();
            chdir(prev_path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, the error might be in the missing parts. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Include an example structure of directories, files and symbolic links that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `while(next_entry = readdir(curr_dir) != NULL)` actually works?!?! It's buggy. Who's teaching you to cram the assignment into the `while()` statement?  `for ( ;; ) { struct dirent *next_entry = readdir(curr_dir); if ( !next_entry ) break; ...` makes it impossible to screw up the assignment.  `while(next_entry = readdir(curr_dir) != NULL)` actually reads as `while(next_entry = (readdir(curr_dir) != NULL))` (note the added `()`s) because `!=` has higher precedence than `-`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I messed up the braces trying to copy the code here without checking it. Do you find it to be okay now that I changed it? Or still you think it's bad practice? I've seen that done (with the added braces) by my teachers and very often in the system manual, but I always wondered if it was good practice. I've never seen a "for" used the way you do. Why for(;;) and not while(1)?

Comment: Constructs such as `while(next_entry = readdir(curr_dir) != NULL);` *are* a bad practice - the looping is "hidden" and easily missed or omitted.  Which you actually did when you asked this question, and continued to miss for a while after it was pointed out to you.  Ask your teachers if they've ever been called in to work at 3 AM because production code was broken, and take their answer into account when you consider their use and acceptance of bug-prone code constructs.  **ALWAY** use braces in loops, even if all they hold is a single `;`. Then it's clear you meant to create an empty loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to modify my code not to navigate files which are symbolic links, but it still navigates those aliases

`stat()` will never return data such that `S_ISLNK(info.st_mode)` is true (except see below).  Per [the POSIX `stat()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/stat.html):

> If the named file is a symbolic link, the `stat()` function shall continue pathname resolution using the contents of the symbolic link, and shall return information pertaining to the resulting file if the file exists.

and

> The `lstat()` function shall be equivalent to stat(), except when path refers to a symbolic link. In that case `lstat()` shall return information about the link, while stat() shall return information about the file the link references.

You need to replace

```
stat(entry_name, &info);
if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode) && !S_ISLNK(info.st_mode)){ 
  //navigate to next_entry
}
```

with

```
int rc = lstat(entry_name, &info);
if((rc==0) && S_ISDIR(info.st_mode) && !S_ISLNK(info.st_mode)){ 
  //navigate to next_entry
}
```

Note also the return value from `[l]stat()` needs to be checked.  The contents of the `info` struct will not mean anything if the `[l]stat()` call fails, so the checks using `ISDIR()` and `ISLNK()` could return any value.